# How to show the column index in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Here's this spreadsheet screenshot below

[image]

What is the formula to be used for cell **H1** such that this can be automated for the rest of row **1**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
=COLUMN(H1)-1
```

may be entered in H1 to return the desired result.

Comment: I tried it, and it shows the column number. `=COLUMN(H1)-1` shows the correct output. You may need to edit your answer so it could properly address the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't look carefully enough at the question. Yes, you would just subtract 1; answer edited.

Comment: I see you have edited the answer to include the reference to H1 - this would make the statement that follows incorrect (it would only work when entered in column H).

Comment: I have alse edited the question because it's quite confusing